# How to model a business process

Tags: neo4j, task, sequence, business-process-management, business-rules

I am trying to model a business process in Neo4j that describes both the sequence and dependencies.

In fact I want to model a supply chain in which items get bought from suppliers, the items get consumed in certain quantities during manufacturing to produce an item that is sold to a customer. To manufacture the item requires a sequence of operations, each of which require a piece of machinery and and operator. The operation takes a certain amount of time and cannot proceed if the raw materials, machinery, and operators are not available.

I searched the web for days, but cannot find what I need. There are a few links for capturing events, such as 911 calls.

But I am trying to build a model for planning, so I need to describe the ideal process and then determine when items need to be produced in which quantities to meet customer demand. And of course I also need to determine when raw materials need to be purchased from suppliers so that they are available when needed in manufacturing.

So I need a way to represent the ideal process, and then a way to represent the anticipated time-series that represents the events before they happen.

Comment: I think your question is too broad to be dealt with here. If you want to model a business process (and not data, since you are talking about Neo4j), I suggest you look at BPMN or UML as examples of business process modeling languages. At first glance, your example could be easily modeled in any of these two (since you are implementing data-driven decisions, you could also use [DMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_Model_and_Notation) together with BPMN). I suggest to give it a try with any of these and get back here if you get stuck.

Comment: Look at the Cadence Workflow (cadenceworkflow.io). It allows modeling a business process as normal code.